# Placing function buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to put these two buttons next to each other?
I call them as a function: [picture][1]

Here is my code:

```
 export default class CreditCardForm extends React.Component {
 constructor () {
 super()}

 render() {;
   return (
     <div>
       <ButtonNew />
       <ButtonExisting />
     </ div>
   )
 }
}
```

Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkUDC.jpg

Comment: Sounds like you are wanting to use css to position them next to each other. Have a look at flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two buttons sharing a row in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485653/two-buttons-sharing-a-row-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways to do that, you only need to put some css to your components, but quick and easy: Put a style on your components with the css you want:

```
 <ButtonNew style={{float:'left'}} />
 <ButtonExisting style={{float:'left'}} />
```

see [Four ways to style components](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822)

You can check the grid system of [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)